# Audio signal correction

Tags: audio, signal-processing, aws-amplify

I have recorded an audio.

I dont know how it happened that only one sided speech is recorded and the other speech is recorded with a very low sound.
Is there any solution to amplify the other side signal.
any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add a sample, or a more detailed description, both speakers are recorded with the same microphone? One microphone or multiple. I tell you in advance that when you amplify the voice of the speaker that has low volume it will increase noise as well

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Speakers are recorded with the different microphones. One is mine )Signal A) and the rest are like on the other side (signal B) like a Zoom/Teams meeting. I tried it with differnt softwares to amplify the signal B but noise is increasing as well. any suggestions please

Comment: @2017_John you might want to add a language tag to reach the right audience. You also might have more luck at https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably more appropriately asked at a forum where recording and mixing is discussed. For example: https://sound.stackexchange.com/

The ideal would be to improve your recording situation, to control factors so the sound are more closely matched. (Match microphones, isolate the speakers from environmental sounds, optimize input levels, etc.)

After that, the next option or step is to pre-process your audio files with a tool like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/). Use this or another DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) tool to match amplitudes or employ noise filtering or a range of other tools.

Audio processing is both tricky (an "art") and cpu intensive, so it's good to get as much of this handled as possible before the sounds are imported into a program.